# QML Connections not working in newly inserted row?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel

As an example, I took [the official example from Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-models-abstractitemmodel-example.html) and added a few lines to demonstrate the problem:

model.h:

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStringList>

//![0]
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size);
//![0]

    QString type() const;
    QString size() const;

private:
    QString m_type;
    QString m_size;
//![1]
};

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(int myProperty READ myProperty NOTIFY myPropertyChanged)

signals:
    void myPropertyChanged();

public:
    enum AnimalRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };

    AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);
//![1]

    void addAnimal(const Animal &animal);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    // my code starts
    virtual bool insertRows(int position, int rows,
                            const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex()) override;
    virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const override {
        return QAbstractListModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    }
    int myProperty() const {
        return m_myProperty;
    }
    int m_myProperty;

public slots:
    void addAnimal();
        // my code ends

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Animal> m_animals;
//![2]
};
//![2]
```

model.cpp:

```
#include "model.h"

Animal::Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size)
    : m_type(type), m_size(size)
{
}

QString Animal::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

QString Animal::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

AnimalModel::AnimalModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
    , m_myProperty(0)
{
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal(const Animal &animal)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_animals << animal;
    endInsertRows();
}

int AnimalModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_animals.count();
}

QVariant AnimalModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_animals.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Animal &animal = m_animals[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return animal.type();
    else if (role == SizeRole)
        return animal.size();
    return QVariant();
}

bool AnimalModel::insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    beginInsertRows(index, position, position + rows - 1);

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
        m_animals.insert(position, Animal("new type", "new animal"));
    }

    endInsertRows();

    return true;
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal()
{
    insertRow(0);

    m_myProperty = m_animals.count();
    emit myPropertyChanged();
}

//![0]
QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[SizeRole] = "size";
    return roles;
}
//![0]
```

and finally view.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

//![0]
Column {
    ListView {
        id: list
        width: 200; height: 250

        model: myModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: index + ": Animal: " + type + ", " + size + ", " + list.model.myProperty

            Connections {
                target: myModel
                onMyPropertyChanged: {
                    console.log(index + ", " + list.model.myProperty)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Button {
        onClicked: {
            myModel.addAnimal()
        }
    }
}

//![0]
```

Pretty simple. After pushing the button and calling `addAnimal()` I would expect to see console output like this:

```
qml: 0, 4
qml: 1, 4
qml: 2, 4
qml: 3, 4
```

but instead I see this:

```
qml: 1, 4
qml: 2, 4
qml: 3, 4
```

However the signal is surely emitted (and received) because the UI not only shows the newly added item with updated animal list size but also all the other rows have been updated. So why the new row didn't receive `onMyPropertyChanged` ?

Is this a Qt bug? I'm using Qt 5.9.5.

[image: animal list size == 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `insertRow(0)` you are inserting in position 0, so the previous 0 element will now be the one that has the connection and will receive the signal.

So the last inserted element will have no connection when the clicked is pressed so it will not be notified.

---

To illustrate I will explain it step by step:

- In the first insert there are no elements so no one receives the signal.
- In the second insertion, the previous 0 element will be the current 1 and it has the connection so it will be notified.
- In the third insertion the previous 0 element will be the current 1 and the previous one will be the current 2 so the 1, 2 have the connection and will be notified.

In conclusion the creation of the delegate is after the issuance of the `myPropertyChanged` signal, so the delegate inserted will not be notified, the others will, and since your insertion is always in the first position it will never be printed `qml: 0, n`

To understand graphically assume that there are delegates and as they already exist they will receive the notification:

```
                                            0           0  (+)
0 (+)                                       1  (+)      1  (+)
1 (+)                                       2  (+)      2  (+)
2 (+)                                       3  (+)      3  (+)
... --> clicked --> myPropertyChanged -->  ...     -->  4  (+)
n (+)                                      n+1 (+)     n+1 (+)
```

(+): indicates that there is connection

---

**More explanation:**

To be clear, the rules of the event loop are as follows: sequential tasks are carried out with priority, calls to signals are made wait if they are not urgent.

Let's analyze your code in more detail:

1. insertRow(0);
2. m_myProperty = m_animals.count();
3. emit myPropertyChanged();

The previous lines are executed sequentially, so at the end of step one there is already a new element in the model, but the view has not been updated since for this the code must return to the event-loop and for that it must finish executing the step 3.

Just after finishing step 3, the signal tasks are executed, so what you do is create is create the delegate and the connection, so now you give priority to the `myPropertyChanged` signal and call the existing connections minus the last one since it did not exist when the signal was emitted.

---

In conclusion only the slots that exist when the signal emits the signal will be called, the new connections that are created immediately after the signal emission until the slot call will not be called.

Comment: Just a minor correction: the list starts with three pre-filled animals, so the first bullet point is not correct. You write "the creation of the delegate is after the issuance of the myPropertyChanged signal" -- fair enough but then when exactly is the delegate created?

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
In my first point I assumed that there are 0 delegates, but in any case my explanation is valid, if there are 3 delegates they will be notified. The connection is given after the creation of the delegate.

Comment: What I still don't get is why the delegate is not created soon enough? I mean, we insert a row, right. The signal rowsInserted() is emitted. Now I'd assume that somewhere at this point the item and delegate is created. And I call emit myPropertyChanged(); after that. So how come it's too soon for the poor delegate?

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
Wait a moment, I am adding just that in my response

Comment: @MiroKropacek see my explanation

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I had no idea. Is there a way to know when is the signal safe to emit? Without additonal calls/hacks in Component.onCompleted or similar? (not sure whether even that works...)

Comment: @MiroKropacek mmm, it will be with a bit of hack since you want to emit the signal from the model, and the model is never notified about any change in the view unless the view modified the data. Maybe there is a signal in the view that indicates when a new delegate has been inserted, maybe the onCompleted delegate and there you emit the signal.

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
I have a curiosity, why are you going to use that signal?

Comment: @ eyllanesc: one of my use cases is having TextField's readOnly flag depend on the state of such variable. However while typing this I have realised that maybe I can avoid this asynchronous hell with introduction of a separate role. Anyway, your input has been most helpful!

Comment: @MiroKropacek hahaha, that's what the roles are for. :)

Comment: despite my initial optimism I have realised that using a role doesn't really solve the problem: if I set a role to something, to take effect I have to call emit dataChanged(), i.e. leading me back to square one. How would you cleanly solve the situation where all items are read only and after insertRow(0) you want to have that 0th row editable/writable based on some internal property?

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
Let's go to the problem in particular, what would be the default status of the readOnly flag?, I think the solution is the roles.

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
the role of the new QModelIndex must have a default value and you must make a binding with the flag, so when the delegate is created the binding will also exist and will be notified of the role change.

Comment: The initial idea was to have something like readOnly: !editing (where 'editing' would be the role, the old version was something like readOnly: index != myModel.editingIndex). 'editing' role would return false by default and for any newly created item it would be set to true.

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
Until now I see that it works correctly, so far your model is only read because it does not have the setData() method, if you have implemented the setData() method you could indicate in detail what the error is, as it is caused.

Comment: @MiroKropacek 
Also to understand your problem you could share your progress through github.

Comment: just in case I make the connection using the following: `delegate: TextEdit {`
                `text: index + ": Animal: " + type + ", " + size`
                `readOnly: editing`
            `}`

Comment: Actually it seems I have another problem - related to TextField's focus. I need to take a closer look and perhaps open another question. Thank you for your valuable advice.